# How to get this query to execute?

Tags: sql

I have the following query that returns an error when I try to run it in SQL Server.

```
-- Returns the first name, last name, and state of each person in my_contacts
SELECT my_contacts.first_name, my_contacts.last_name, zip_code.[state]
FROM my_contacts
INNER JOIN
state
ON my_contacts.zip_code = zip_code.zip_code
```

I thought it may error out because status is a reserved keyword in SQL so I put it in [], but I still get an error.  This is the error message:

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'state'.

I am running out of ideas so would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
-- Returns the first name, last name, and state of each person in my_contacts
SELECT my_contacts.first_name, my_contacts.last_name, zip_code.state
FROM my_contacts
INNER JOIN
zip_code
ON my_contacts.zip_code = zip_code.zip_code
```

The tables are `my_contacts` and `zip_code`.